Postgres `generatedAs` and `storedAs` in Laravel migaration
I have this migration. I am using Postgres, I found that generatedAs and storedAs are supported by Postgres.. I am a beginner in Postgres.
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->bigIncrements('id');
       $table->string('first_name');
       $table->string('last_name');
       $table->string('full_name')->generatedAs("first_name || ' ' || last_name"); // error
       $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
       $table->string('status')->storedAs("CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END"); // error
        });

The error is
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "first_name"
LINE 1: ...r(255) not null generated by default as identity (first_name...
                                                             ^ (Connection: pgsql, SQL: create table "users" ("id" bigserial not null primary key, "first_name" varchar(255) not null, "last_name" varchar(255) not null, "full_name" varchar(255) not null generated by default as identity (first_name || ' ' || last_name), "active" boolean not null default '0', "status" varchar(255) not null generated always as (CASE WHEN active = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END) stored))


generatedAs is for "Creat[ing] an identity column with specified sequence options". As an identity column, it will only accept data types acceptable for use as a Postgres sequence - smallint, integer, and bigint.
Even if it would take a string, "first + last name" is a bad idea for an identity - there's more than one John Doe in the world. Use storedAs instead. (You might also consider an accessor for the full name value instead of storing redundant data like this.)
